# Hibernate:Data is not being populated in the table

Tags: hibernate

I wrote a sample Hibernate program the table with columns is created when i run the program but the data isnt being populated in the table  .Can someone please help me out.

```
My model bean is :

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class student {
private String name;
private int id;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

The class where configuration and sessions is written is:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import com.hibernate.data.Employee;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    AnnotationConfiguration config=new AnnotationConfiguration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(student.class);
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
    SessionFactory factory=config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    student s =new student();
    s.setId(1);
    s.setName("vamsi");
    s.setId(2);
    s.setName("krishna");
    subjects s1 =new subjects();
    session.save(s);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:C:\Users\krishna\Desktop\hsqldb-2.2.6</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>


        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- 
        Drop and re-create the database schema on startup
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>
   -->


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: This at least create a student with id=2 and without name?

Comment: i made the changes and saved two objects with id=1 and id=2

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have already created the table? And that the table is as per your requirements?

I myself am learning Hibernate, and I find these few problems with your code:

a) `@Column(name = "Name")` annotation should be there on top of your `Name` getter setters.

b) Also, I think in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`, it should say:

```
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Because otherwise, its doing nothing. With your current code, it should at least have populated the `id`. Hibernate docs explain this really well.

c) Besides, you're only saving the user with `id` 2 if you look close enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i made the changes and saved two objects with id=1 and id=2  and added the entry in hibernate.cfg.xml but still data isnt being updated .

Comment: I still think there's something wrong with your hibernate.cfg.xml. In the "connection.url" property, you're supposed to give the URL to your database. For instance, mine looks like: 
**jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someDB**, where **someDB** is my database. Are you sure you aren't getting an error?

Comment: Also, add this line into your code, with the correct package reference: `config.addAnnotatedClass(com.something.student.class);` somewhere before the SchemaExport line. Also, after looking at your code again, I realized the update in hibernate.cfg.xml wasn't necessary.